# Can't get the subclass to inherit or override from the superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, overriding

I'm positive I covered the basics. I put @Override before overriding methods. I made sure to include 'extends Super' on the line of the class. I can't override the constructor either. I passed the right amount of variables of the correct type and it gives me an error message saying 'actual and formal argument lists differ in length.' Along with errors not reading the static variables from the TuitionConstants class.

```
// This is the super class
public abstract class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

        private int mCredits;
        private String mFirstName;
        private String mId;
        private String mLastName;
        private double mTuition;

    public Student(String pId, String pFirstName, String pLastName) {
        mId = pId;
        mFirstName = pFirstName;
        mLastName = pLastName;
    }

    public abstract void calcTuition();

    @Override
        public int compareTo(Student pStudent) {
        return getId().compareTo(pStudent.getId());
    }

    public int getCredits() {
        return mCredits;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return mFirstName;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return mLastName;
    }

    public double getTuition() {
        return mTuition;
    }

    public void setCredits(int pCredits) {
        mCredits = pCredits;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String pFirstName) {
        mFirstName = pFirstName;
    }

    public void setId(String pId) {
        mId = pId;
    }

    public void setlastName(String pLastName) {
        mLastName = pLastName;
    }

    protected void setTuition(double pTuition) {
        mTuition = pTuition;
    }

}
```

```
import p02.Student;
import p02.TuitionConstants;

public class OnCampusStudent extends Student {

    public static final int RESIDENT = 1;
    public static final int NON_RESIDENT = 2;
    private int mResident;
    private double mProgramFee;

//Error on this constructor. Says 'actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    public OnCampusStudent(String pId, String pFirstName, String pLastName) {
        super(pId, pFirstName, pLastName);
    }

// Errors on this method. On @Override line:"method does not override or implement a method 
// from a supertype. Also on the lines that call getCredits(), it says "cannot find symbol,"
// but it's a method from the superclass. Same "cannot find symbol" error on the lines that call
// the static variables from the TuitionConstants class.
    @Override
    public void calcTuition() {
        double t;
        if (getResidency() == RESIDENT) {
            t = TuitionConstants.ONCAMP_RES_BASE;
        } else {
            t = TuitionConstants.ONCAMP_NONRES_BASE;
        }
        t = t + getProgramFee();
        if (getCredits() > TuitionConstants.ONCAMP_MAX_CREDITS) {
            t = t + (getCredits() - TuitionConstants.ONCAMP.MAX.CREDITS) * TuitionConstants.ONCAMP_ADD_CREDITS;
        }
        setTuition(t);
    }
}
```

```
// Here is the TuitionConstants Class.
public class TuitionConstants {

    public static final int ONCAMP_ADD_CREDITS = 475;
    public static final int ONCAMP_MAX_CREDITS = 18;
    public static final int ONCAMP_NONRES_BASE = 14875;
    public static final int ONCAMP_RES_BASE = 7575;
    public static final int ONLINE_CREDIT_RATE = 950;
    public static final int ONLINE_TECH_FEE = 75;

}
```

Comment: Other than not being able to find the `TuitionConstants`, your code doesn't show errors for me. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: You need to show us which line is causing the error. Also, please, try to make your example as small as it is possible. You really don't need all these fields and setters to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Could you provide the error that you are seeing?

Comment: @Charles.Hi The errors I'm getting are "actual and formal argument lists differ in length" at the constructor of the subclass.

Comment: You don't show us the package in which `Student` is defined. Are you sure, you are referencing the right `Student` class?

Comment: @MoritzPetersen Sorry, I'm still pretty new to this. I'm not completely sure what you're referring to, but all the classes are under a package named ' P02'

Comment: have you recompiled your Student class before trying to compile your sub class?

Comment: I see following issue with your code :a.  getResidency() and getProgramFee() methods are not defined. b.  TuitionConstants.ONCAMP.MAX.CREDITS should be   TuitionConstants.ONCAMP_MAX_CREDITS

Comment: @Stultuske I haven't. My Student class shows no errors so I didn't think I would need to mess with it.

Comment: @akshayapandey Those methods are defined in my actual class, I just chose to leave those out for this question to not make the post so lengthy. But thank you for that second part, I didn't catch that.

Comment: @DanielCamacho each time you make changes in a class, you need to recompile it, otherwise the other classes still work with the older compiled version. That might cause your issues. it's not about showing errors or not, and it's not messing with it, it's just making sure the compiled version is the last up to date one

Comment: @DanielCamacho I compiled your code on my side and it seems like everything is good, I was able to run it. Try cleaning up your project and recompile your classes.

Comment: @Stultuske roger that, thank you for the advice. For this code I was just following a pseudocode that was provided by the professor for my class.

Comment: @Charles.Hi Thank you,I appreciate your help.

Comment: @DanielCamacho I don't really understand how that is related. Did you make changes to your Student class after you compiled it?

Comment: @Stultuske I didn't.

Comment: Do that, that should fix those issues

Comment: @Stultuske I will do that, thanks for the guidance.